# How does Object Oriented Programming work?

Tags: java, oop

I am not sure about some things in OOP.

If I have `Class1`, which has some private field, for example `private Field field1`, and make

```
getField1 () {
    return field1;
}
```

then I have some class with constructor

```
public Class2 (Field field) { 
    someMethod(field);
}
```

And then I call constructor of Class2 in Class3 like:

```
Class2 cl = new Class2(instanceOfClass1.getField1());
```

And now the question: Am I working with `field1` of `instanceOfClass1` in `someMethod(field)`?

Comment: is this java or C# or generic OOP?

Comment: I think it does not matter, but it is java.

Comment: It can matter. Java passes everything by value whereas C/C++ can use pointers and references.

Comment: Java passes objects by reference, always.

Comment: Java passes everything by value - this includes primitive types and references. Objects are never passed. For example, `void f(Something x) { x = null; }` followed by `f(a)` doesn't change `a`. Similarly, `void f(Something x) { x.a = 5; }` followed by `f(a)` doesn't change `a` neither - it changes object referenced by `a`. References are copied, referenced objects are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on whether `field` is a value or a reference.

Value types are copied when passed as parameters. Reference types are not; the function is simply handed a "reference" that points back to the original value, and any changes that it makes are reflected in the original value.

Whether a given type is value or reference depends on your particular programming language. Generally speaking, basic integer and boolean types are usually value types, and everything else is up in the air -- some languages make strings values, and others treat them as references, etc.

Edit: Since you mentioned you're using Java, here's a short program that demonstrates value and reference types:

```
class ClassOne {
    public int myInt;
}

class ClassTwo {
    public int myInt;
    public ClassTwo(ClassOne c)
    {
        myInt = c.myInt;
        c.myInt = 3;
    }
}

public class main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ClassOne c = new ClassOne();
        c.myInt = 1;
        System.out.println("C1: " + c.myInt);

        ClassTwo c2 = new ClassTwo(c);
        System.out.println("C2: " + c2.myInt);
        System.out.println("C1: " + c.myInt);

    }
}
```

Running this program will give the output:

```
C1: 1
C2: 1
C1: 3
```

In this program, both ClassOne and ClassTwo contain an integer field -- a value type. ClassTwo takes a ClassOne parameter -- a reference type -- in its constructor, and sets its own integer field based on the value of the ClassOne object it is given, and then changes the ClassOne object's value.

Because classes are reference types, changing the ClassOne object in the ClassTwo constructor causes the *original object* to be changed. (In the main function here, that's `c`.) But because integers are value types, even though `c2` changes the value of `c.myInt` in its constructor, because it sets its *own* value beforehand, `c2.myInt` isn't affected: it retains the original number, because it was copied rather than referenced.

Hopefully this helps clear things up a bit.

Comment: When I create ArrayList<MyClass>, and private MyClass cl; in java, are both reference?

Comment: Class types in Java are always reference types. If you have a field in an object that is of a class type, and you pass that field value to another method, when it modifies the value you gave it, it is modifying the same class object your original field points to. Some classes are designed to be natively immutable to prevent confusion of this kind -- String is the most obvious example. Strings, once created, are not changed -- any operation which could change them (such as toUpperCase or substring) returns a new String instance instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're working with the value contained in it. If it is a mutable object then yes, it is possible to change the state of the instance of Class1 from outside, which violates data protection principles. This is why you should copy mutable types before returning them.

Comment: but what If I need to track exactly that instance, and someMethod(field) put the field to some global lookup? How to solve it with copying?

Comment: If you make a deep copy of a mutable object then any mutations to the object won't affect the copy.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reread your question two or three times to make sure I understood what you're asking.

To recap:

- There is Class1 which contains an field attribute (of type Field?) which is sent back by it's getField1() method.
- There is then Class2 which is apparently has a constructor that accepts an object parameter of Field type and contains a method that uses an instance of Field to trigger a local method in this class.
- You then use a third class to instantiate Class2 and initialize it using an instance of Field using the getField1() method from an instance of Class1.

In the case of Java, providing you've done the necessary instantiation this would mean that the Field instance in Class1 is being used throughout the process. You can verify this using a System.out.println() (this will give you an @ symbol with a series of weird numbers) or using the a.equals(b) method common to all objects.

Here is an interesting link about passing objects by value:
http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp